# Which DLL exports the NtGdiBeginGdiRendering function and how?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to locate the `NtGdiBeginGdiRendering` function in Windows. Which DLL exports this function? Which mechanism adds the NtGdi prefix and to what purpose? What is the difference between calling `NtGdiBeginGdiRendering` and `BeginGdiRendering` (difference in functionality and in calling convention and used modules to call)

Comment: /wininc/ntgdi.h

Comment: There are mentioned more sys and dll's http://filelog.net/func/NtGdiBeginGdiRendering

Comment: Checked all those places - none of them has NtGdiBeginGdiRendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [RoQuOTriX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988547/which-dll-exports-the-ntgdibegingdirendering-function#comment116670797_65988547), I discovered that this function is exported from gdi32.dll.

What was confusing is that gdi32.dll doesn't use the `NtGdi` prefix. It just exports it as `BeginGdiRendering`.

Comment: Note that this is not documented, and that Microsoft can move the implementation of the function around to different DLLs if it likes. Hardcoding this assumption into your application means that your application is subject to break with updates to Windows. If you provided more details in your question about why you needed this information, someone could probably give you an even better solution.

Comment: Also, I just figured out what you were talking about with respect to the prefix. I've rolled back your edits to the question (please don't change the nature of the question after discovering the answer; instead. just explain in the answer what the confusion was). The `NtGdi` prefix means that the function is part of the [Native API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API). The function with the prefix is actually a different function than the one without; they're not the same. However, the one *without* the prefix from gdi32.dll is almost certainly just a stub that calls the Native API fxn.

Comment: Why Microsoft is doing such a thing with changing to other DLLs? What does it mean  "is almost certainly just a stub that calls the Native API fxn" how this Native API fxn call happens?

Comment: The Native API is the underlying implementation, the one that actually does the work of implementing GDI. What you find in gdi32.dll is just a wrapper around the Native API. Most of the wrapper functions are *minimal* wrappers, meaning that they just delegate to the equivalent Native API functions. But some of them add additional value, like parameter-checking, combinations of functions, etc. This is the way it's been implemented since the first version of Windows NT, using a hardware abstraction layer. User-mode developers only ever deal with gdi32.dll. They don't call the Native API directly

Answer (score 0):

`NtGdiBeginGdiRendering` is the kernel mode implementation of `BeginGdiRendering`, located in `win32k.sys`. Whenever your code calls `BeginGdiRendering`, the function transitions the system from user mode to kernel mode and ultimately calls `NtGdiBeginGdiRendering`. (This is called a system call.)

To answer the rest of your question, `BeginGdiRendering` can be only called from user mode, and `NtGdiBeginGdiRendering` can only be called from kernel mode.

Note that it is not a part of the so-called Native API as some people here suggest. Native API is the system call interface exported from `ntdll.dll` only. Here, the system call is exported from `gdi32.dll`.